# hindi Language pack pack for Joomla admin

Tags: php, joomla

anyone help me. i need Hindi language pack for Joomla. I need an Admin can create hindi language pages with typing in Article Manager in Joomla. I tried many pack but no one works fine.

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic (this is not a programming question). Please support the [Joomla proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla-answers) on area51 if you'd like a dedicated Joomla equivalent of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Hindi language pack for Joomla 1.5 that can be downloaded from [here](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/jtranslation/frs/?action=FrsReleaseBrowse&frs_package_id=5155). If you need it for Joomla 2.5 then converting it is pretty easy.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can download Official Joomla 2.5 language page from [here](http://www.bhavyasoft.com/download/file/2-joomla-2-5-hindi-translation-language-pack-download.html)